# How to have a nested required unknown key-value object with Joi

Tags: joi

I am trying to create a schema validation that will accept this:

A:

```
{
 "user_token": "test",
 "accounts":{
   "any_key":[0, 1]
 }
}
```

or this
B:

```
{
 "user_token": "e29a64c4c9f08414cc2999a0166664f8",
 "accounts":{
   "some_other_key":[0, 1]
 }
}
```

but not this
C:

```
{
 "user_token": "e29a64c4c9f08414cc2999a0166664f8",
 "accounts":{}
}
```

it should basically accept an object under `accounts` that would accept any key-value.

I had a look at `.unknown` in [Joi's documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v8.0.3/API.md#objectunknownallow) but I couldn't implement it because what I'm trying to implement this against is an array

```
const statementsSchema = {
  body: Joi.object({
    user_token: Joi.string().required(),
    accounts: Joi.object({
      Joi.array().unknown().required()
    }).required()
  })
}
```

I also tried `.pattern` which almost works but it doesn't enforce the object inside `accounts` required.

```
const statementsSchema = {
  body: Joi.object({
    user_token: Joi.string().required(),
    accounts: Joi.object({}).pattern(/./, Joi.array()).required()
  })
}
```

Is it possible to have `accounts` require a single child array without specifying the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're extremely close. The missing piece is to specify the minimum number of keys allowed in the `accounts` object by using [`object.min()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectminlimit). In your case, the minimum number of keys is `1`.

```
const statementsSchema = {
    body: Joi.object({
        user_token: Joi.string().required(),
        accounts: Joi.object().pattern(/./, Joi.array()).min(1).required()
    })
};
```